# Anonymous user cannot see contributionpage fields in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute, anonymous-user

We have a new wordpress site and have added a basic (to paypal) donation page- worls fine when logged in. but the contribution amount fields aren't showing for anonymous users.

Anonymous user view
[image]

Same page but logged in
[image]

Anonymous users have permissions to:

- make online contribution
- create in profile
- view profile listings and
- forms access all custom data

Anything we've missed?

Comment: I would first check your Wordpress/CiviCRM permissions to make sure anonymous users have "CiviContribute: make online contributions". Go to "Administer" --> "Users and Permissions" --> "Permissions (Access Control)".

Comment: Apologies. I missed your last comment that indicated anonymous users can make online contributions.

Comment: No worries Mark- I;'ll edit the message to make that clearer

Comment: can you try a different WP theme?